# How to rewrite code using then block using javascript, react and cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

i have the code like below which uses lot of nested then clauses. this code is for testing my code written in javascript and react using cypress.

```
{
export const waitForItems = (retries, nrItems) => {
    cy.apiGetItems().then(items => {
        if(items.length!== nrItems && retries > 0) {
            cy.wait(1000);
            return waitForItems(retries -1, nrItems);
        }
        expect(items.length).to.be.equal(nrItems);
    });
};

const item = {
    name: 'name1',
};
const itemFamily = 'ItemFamily1';
const subfamily = {
    name: 'subfamily1',
}

describe('some test', () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.clickButtonByLabel('Click');
        switchUser(USERNAME);
        waitForItems(NUMBEROFRETRIES, NUMBEROFITEMS);

        cy.apiGetItems({ name: item.name })
            .then(createdItem => {
                item.id = createdItem[0].id;
        })
        .then(() => {
            cy.apiGetItemFamily({
                name: itemFamilyName,
            }).then(family => {
                cy.apiGetSubFamily({
                    name: subfamily1.name,
                    item__family__id__in: family[0].id,
                }).then(subfamily => {
                    subfamily1.id = subfamily[0].id; //error here says cannot read 
                    // id of undefined
                    cy.apiPostSomething({
                        ...something,
                        items: [item.id],
                        subfamily: [subfamily1.id],
                    }).then(createdSomething => {
                        something.id = createdSomething.id;
                        cy.apiGetItemVariable({
                            key: ItemVariableName,
                            subfamily__id__in: subfamily1.id,
                        }).then(variable => {
                            cy.apiPostVariableValue({
                                variable: variable[0].id,
                                value: controlValue,
                            }).then(() => {
                                cy.apiGetsubFamily({
                                    name: subfamily1.name,
                            }).then(newControl => {
                                const versions =
                                    newControl[0].versions;
                                const latestVersionControl = versions.find(
                                    v => v.version === '3.9.0'
                                );
                                const id = latestVersionControl.id;
                                cy.apiPatchSomething({
                                    id: Something.id,
                                    controls: [id], 
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The above code works fine. but sometimes i get error "cannot read id of undefined" in the then(subfamily) clause.

i am not sure why subfamily[0] is still not available when trying to assign it like so

```
 .then(subfamily => {
     subfamily1.id = subfamily[0].id;
 }
```

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: The internals of `cy.apiGetSubFamily` cause the problem since you are getting it on it's result. Please provide the code for this.

Comment: Also, can you show where `subfamily1` is from - is it an object initialized outside the test?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>First, you should giv a try to async/await syntax, since you use promise. It'll help you writting easier to read code :</strike>

```js
describe('some test', () => {
    before(async () => { //add async there
        cy.clickButtonByLabel('Click');
        switchUser(USERNAME);
        waitForItems(NUMBEROFRETRIES, NUMBEROFITEMS);

        const createdItem = await cy.apiGetItems({ name : item.name });
        item.id = createdItem[0].id;
        const family = await cy.apiGetItemFamily({ name: itemFamilyName });
        //and so one
    });
});
```

This way, you will write your code in a way that seems synchronous.

For your question about subfamily,

It's probably the return value of `cy.apiGetSubFamily` that doesn't return an array, or is returning an empty array.

**Edit about Cypress :**

The fact that Cypress doesn't work well with Promise as nothing to do with async/await syntax problem. Since Cypress return thenable, async/await SHOULD be usable.

But because of Cypress **paradigm** that handle asynchronus in it's way, the await/async syntax leads to undeterministic results when we await one. More info can be found there : https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1417

Comment: `await cy.apiGetItems()` isn't valid because it does not return a Promise.

Comment: @Vispo My bad. Given the code `cy.apiGetItems({ name: item.name }).then(createdItem => {item.id = createdItem[0].id; })`, I wrongly assumed that it used regular promises. Knowing nothing about the API calls nor Cypress at that time. Thanks.

Comment: @Vispo I just learned that you can use async/await syntax not only on promises, but on thenable objects too. A thenable is an object that implements a then method. So, my statement about async/await was correct. Just test that : `const test = { then : callback => setTimeout(callback, 2000) };
(async () => { console.log('start'); await test; console.log('done !');  })();`

Comment: MDN says thenable is awaitable,, but please **test it**. Any command that yields a Chainable will give you `null` result on `await`.

Comment: @user16695029 So, as I wasn't satisfied by those explanations, I digged a little more. It's a little bit more complicated than just 'can't work with async/await because not promise', since async/await can work with thenable that are not promises. In fact, reading https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1417 , the promise will resolve unconsistently (value, null or undefined). It's undeterministic, but this as nothing to do with async/await or promises. It's cypress **paradigm** that cause that. Why and How are important. I would never have argued against a well explained assertion.